# Can't play audio files on iOS device, works on emulator

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I keep getting this error when I try to play local audio files which are saved on a custom directory

```
Error (-11849) Operation Stopped 
 Stack #0      AudioPlayer._load (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:850:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      AudioPlayer._setPlatformActive.setPlatform (package:just_audio/just_audio.dart:1435:28)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

this is the file path

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/55D5A61A-733C-4129-85AE-5757210F3C1A/Documents/Networking/Voice Notes/161/1673927478163913.aac

this is how I initialise just_audio

```
  Future<void> initAudioPlayer() async {
    print(widget.filePath);
    await player.setFilePath(widget.filePath);
  }
```

just_audio: ^0.9.23

Comment: Solved this by changing the audio recording library to [record](https://pub.dev/packages/record), flutter sound was creating invalid audio files

Answer (score 0):

Error -11849 is [AVError.Code.failedToLoadMediaData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/averror/code/failedtoloadmediadata).

It's difficult to say much without seeing code, but it seems likely to be some problem with being able to access the file... either it doesn't exist on the device, or the path is incorrect, or the app does not have access to the directory in which the file resides.

See also

- [flutter: (-11849) Operation Stopped For Asset File](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/441)
- [Can't play mp3 file from local storage](https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/issues/520)